# Storing mapreduce intermediate output on a remote server

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, storage, iscsi

I use a hadoop (version 1.2.0) cluster of 16 nodes, one with a public IP (the master) and 15 connected through a private network (the slaves).

**Is it possible to use a remote server (in addition to these 16 nodes) for storing the output of the mappers?** The problem is that the nodes are running out of disk space during the map phase and I cannot compress map output any more.

I know that `mapred.local.dir`in `mapred-site.xml` is used to set a comma-separated list of dirs where the tmp files are stored. Ideally, I would like to have one local dir (the default one) and one directory on the remote server. When the local disk fills, then I would like to use the remote disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the [iSCSI technology](http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_iSCSI_Targets_on_Linux). A technician helped us out to achieve that, so unfortunately I am not able to provide more details on that.

We mounted the remote disk to a local path (`/mnt/disk`) of each slave node, and created a `tmp` file there, with `rwx` priviledges for all users.

Then, we changed the `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/mapred-site.xml` file and added the property:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.local.dir</name>
    <value>/mnt/disk/tmp</value>
</property>
```

Initially, we had two, comma-separated values for that property, with the first being the default value, but it still didn't work as expected (we still got some "No space left on device" errors). So we left only one value there.

Answer (score 3):

I am not very sure about about this but as per the link (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)  it says that:

> The local directory is a directory where MapReduce stores intermediate data files.
>   May be a comma-separated **list of directories on different devices in
>   order to spread disk i/o**. Directories that do not exist are ignored.

Also there are some other properties which you should check out. These might be of help:

> 1. **mapreduce.tasktracker.local.dir.minspacestart**: If the space in mapreduce.cluster.local.dir drops under this, do not ask for more tasks. Value in bytes
> 2. **mapreduce.tasktracker.local.dir.minspacekill**: If the space in mapreduce.cluster.local.dir drops under this, do not ask more tasks until all the current ones have finished and cleaned up. Also, to save the rest of the tasks we have running, kill one of them, to clean up some space. Start with the reduce tasks, then go with the ones that have finished the least. Value in bytes.

Comment: +1 for the two properties, that seem very useful, indeed. Thanks! I will have a deeper look into these. I already knew the first part of the answer, my question is how do I do this.